# Coin toss, probability for less than expected tails?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A fair coin is tossed 500 times. What is the probability that the number of tails differs from expected value ( 250 ) by more than 30?

Comment: What have you tried?  You are probably expected to use the [normal approximation to the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of tails. Then: $\mathbb E(X)=500\cdot 0.5=250, \sigma =\sqrt{500\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5}=5\sqrt{5}\approx 11.18$.

You need to find:
$$P(|X-250|>30)=P(X<220 \ \cup \ X>280)=P(X<220)+P(X>280)=\\
P(\frac{X-0.5-250}{5\sqrt{5}}<\frac{220-0.5-250}{5\sqrt{5}})+P(\frac{X+0.5-250}{5\sqrt{5}}>\frac{280+0.5-250}{5\sqrt{5}})=\\
P(Z<-2.728)+P(Z>2.728)=\\
0.003+0.003=0.006.$$
Reference: [Normal approximation of binomial distribution.](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/binomial-theorem/normal-approximation-to-the-binomial/)

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the number of tails out of $500$ flips.
I would imagine the answer would go something like
\begin{align}
P(|T-250|>30) &= \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{219} \binom{500}{i} + \sum_{i=281}^{500} \binom{500}{i}}{2^{500}} \\
&=\frac{ 2\sum_{i=1}^{219} \binom{500}{i}}{2^{500}} \\
\end{align}
where we have a total of $2^{500}$ possible outcomes, and we count how many outcomes have $x$ number of tails for every $x$ satisfying $|x-250|>30$.

Comment: +1, WA [answers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bi%3D1+to+219%7D+binom(500,i)%2F2%5E499) $0.006315...$